# Why my springboot app with freemarker doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I tried a springboot web application with freemarker. 
In the bootstrap class there's a request-handling method:

```
@RequestMapping("/showAddPage")
   String showAddPage(){
     return "showAdd";
 }
```

And i had my template, named "showAdd.ftl" ,lying in the directory of "resources/templates".

I also added freemarker's starter of springboot in pom.xml.

But when i request "localhost:8080/showAddPage", it retured a String, "showAdd", instead of the rendered content of the template "showAdd.ftl".

It doesn't render my showAdd.ftl. 
Why could this happen?

Comment: Do you use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`?

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah... haven't seen your comment. you're right! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must add Servlet Mapping to your DispatcherServlet ;
There is one sample :
https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/

It would help you

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that i uesed a RestController(an spring annotation) instead of Controller(an spring annotation) at the class level of my bootstrap class.. .This problem was solved by replacing RestController(an spring annotation) with Controller(an spring annotation)。anyway, thx a lot :) –